# onAfterRendering hook for smartform in UI5

Tags: sapui5

In my app i have an XML view that consists of a [smartform](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/99e33bdfde074bb48d2e603fa5ecd2d0.html). I have a need to access  an input element(via `sap.ui.getCore().byId()`) that becomes available after the smartform is  parsed and rendered.

The [`onAfterRendering`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.core.mvc.Controller.html#onAfterRendering) in the controller for my view triggers as soon as the view is rendered(i get all my non-smartform elements like title etc.), but before the smartform is parsed and rendered. A rudimentary test via an `alert` also proved this visually.

Is there any event that is triggered after the smartform has rendered which i can hook into to access my input element?

The developer guide [walkthrough](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/guide/f712d30f9e2d4abd9670263f89542f2b.html) is extending the smartform and thus has its `init` method, but in my case i am extending the basecontroller and my init is for the page view.

Thanks for any pointers.

My View:

```
<mvc:View
controllerName="myns.controller.Add"
xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns:semantic="sap.m.semantic"
xmlns:smartfield="sap.ui.comp.smartfield"
xmlns:smartform="sap.ui.comp.smartform"
xmlns="sap.m">
<semantic:FullscreenPage
    id="page"
    title="{i18n>addPageTitle}"
    showNavButton="true"
    navButtonPress="onNavBack">
    <semantic:content>
        <smartform:SmartForm
            id="form"
            editable="true"
            title="{i18n>formTitle}"
            class="sapUiResponsiveMargin" >
            <smartform:Group
                id="formGroup"
                label="{i18n>formGroupLabel}">
                <smartform:GroupElement>
                    <smartfield:SmartField
                        id="nameField"
                        value="{Name}"   />
                </smartform:GroupElement>
            </smartform:Group>
        </smartform:SmartForm>
    </semantic:content>
    <semantic:saveAction>
        <semantic:SaveAction id="save" press="onSave"/>
    </semantic:saveAction>
    <semantic:cancelAction>
        <semantic:CancelAction id="cancel" press="onCancel"/>
    </semantic:cancelAction>
</semantic:FullscreenPage>
```

My Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
"myns/controller/BaseController",
"sap/ui/core/routing/History",
"sap/m/MessageToast"
],function(BaseController, History, MessageToast){
"use strict";
return BaseController.extend("myns.controller.Add",{
     onInit: function(){
         this.getRouter().getRoute("add").attachPatternMatched(this._onRouteMatched, this);
     },
     onAfterRendering: function(){
        //I tried my sap.ui.getCore().byId() here but does not work
        //An alert shows me this triggers before the smartform is rendered but 
        //after all the other non-smartform elements have rendered
     },
    _onRouteMatched: function(){
        // register for metadata loaded events
        var oModel = this.getModel();
        oModel.metadataLoaded().then(this._onMetadataLoaded.bind(this));
    },
    _onMetadataLoaded:function(){
        //code here....
    },
     onNavBack: function(){
        //code here....
     }
});
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look for when `SmartForm` is added to the DOM with `DOMNodeInserted` event of `jQuery`.
For this you can use it's `id` to identify the `SmartForm` has been added to the `DOM`.

Every `UI5` element gets some prefix after it has been added to the DOM.

for e.g. __xmlview0--form.

So to make sure required form is added you can `split` the id of added element, then compare it with id which you have given.

Although it's not optimal solution, but you can try.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
        var aId = $(event.target).attr("id").split("--");
        var id = aId[aId.length - 1];
        if (id) {
            if (id == "form") {
                // smart form fields are accessible here
                $(document).unbind("DOMNodeInserted");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is an interesting solution, and 'almost' the answer to the primary question. I guess it would be the perfect answer if there isn't any inbuilt event emitted by UI5 for sure. Since there is tight coupling with jQuery, this will definitely work. Reading through the DOM was always an option, but i wasn't sure if there were existing hooks that i may missed out.

Comment: Another option i am considering is to have [nested views](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/docs/guide/df8c9c3d79b54c928855162bafcd88ee.html) with my smartform having its own view and controller (and thus an `init` and `onAfterRendering`). I haven't tried this, but theoretically it looks a viable option.

Comment: I did try the nested route, and the had the same issues in `onAfterRendering` within the nested view as well. I had to additionally attach events (focus/blur etc) to some of the fields so i went both the nested route as well as added the `DOMNodeInserted` event from your solution. For some reason the `attachBrowserEvent` wasn't working, so i used jQuery to attach the events. I am flagging your solution as answered since i am quite sure by now that there are no straightforward hooks.

Comment: Thanks Arun, glad it helped! :)

Answer (score 0):

My final solution (for now and uses the accepted answer provided by @Dopedev):

*(in controller for the nested view containing the smartform)*

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    $(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
        var elem = $(event.target);
        var aId = elem.attr("id").split("--");
        var id = aId[aId.length - 1];
        if (id) {
            if (id == "nameField") {
                elem.find("input").on({
                    focus: function(oEvent) {
                        //code here;
                    },
                    blur: function(oEvent) {
                        //code here;
                    }
                });
                /*
               elem.find("input").get(0).attachBrowserEvent("focus", function(evt) {
                    //code here
                }).attachBrowserEvent("blur", function(ev) {
                    //code here
                });
                */
                $(document).unbind("DOMNodeInserted");
            }
        }
    });
}
```