# Waiting for sap.ui.table.Table rendered after bound model has changed

Tags: sapui5

I have sap.ui.table.Table which rows are bound to an JSONModel.

`var oListModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
//oTable created here (sap.ui.table.Table)
oTable.setModel(oListModel);
oTable.bindRows("/");`

When the table is rendered, i.e. the DOM is created for this table, i need to reference to the DOM to pass the DOM elements (table rows) to a library which will make them draggable.

My problem is: How do i know when the DOM for the table is created after the model has been changed and the table is rerendered? I didnt find any listener. The view controller's listener onAfterRendering() didn't help me.

The model is filled with data after a XMLHTTPRequest is successful. When i set the model in the success handler of the xht request and try to access the DOM elments directly afterwards they don't exist yet.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue recently where i had to access an element after a smartform (where the element is present) rendered onto the view. I posted my query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37919758/onafterrendering-hook-for-smartform-in-ui5) as well as my final solution (based on the accepted answer of @Dopedev). I am using XML views  - including nested XML views - here however and the `onAfterRendering` didn't help for me as well.

I guess you could look at this solution - like it's mentioned in the accepted answer, it may not be an optimal solution, but it sure works. In my case there is not much of a performance issue with the binding of the `DOMNodeInserted` since it is being called in the `onAfterRendering` of the nested view that consists of only the smartform with an immediate unbinding upon finding.

The condition `if (id === "yourtableid") { }` should be enough to identify and pass on. Since you have a table and thus several child nodes, unbinding is imperative at this point.

[Mutation Observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) is the preferred method but i guess you may need to check the browser compatibility table at the end of the page to see if it matches your requirements. There is an example [here](http://gabrieleromanato.name/jquery-detecting-new-elements-with-the-mutationobserver-object/). I have used Mutation Observer (outside of a SAPUI5/openUI5 environment) earlier and found it very convenient(and performant) to listen to DOM insert events. In fact the [sap.ui.dt](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.dt/src/sap/ui/dt) package consists of [MutationObserver.js](https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.dt/src/sap/ui/dt/MutationObserver.js)

Comment: Sap.ui.dt has a drop and drag plugin, but not sure if it registers the mouse/touch events using mutations

Comment: Looks like a delegate https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.ui.dt/src/sap/ui/dt/plugin/DragDrop.js

Comment: the solution you refered to looks promising. i will try this and inform you soon if i have success or not.

Comment: this worked! when i filter the table the DOM nodes are created again when i sort the DOM nodes aren't created again just the innerHTML is changed as it seems. now i need to find out, how i can write a handler like "onAfterSorted" which is triggered after the table is sorted.

Comment: That's great to know! I have to check the `addEventDelegate` mentioned by @jasper-07 since it does look promising in my scenario.

Answer (score 3):

You can add an event delegate

```
var oMyTable = new sap.ui.table.Table();
oMyTable.addEventDelegate({
   onAfterRendering: function() {
      $table = this.getDomRef() ....
   }
});
```

a better way is to extend the control see [Using addDelegate to extend a control to use third party functionality](http://scn.sap.com/community/developer-center/front-end/blog/2014/05/24/using-adddelegate-to-extend-a-control-to-use-third-party-functionality)

UPDATE
the example in that blog doesn't work anymore [fixed here](http://jsbin.com/loqeguridu/edit?html,output)

Comment: jQuery-UI looks like its not compatible with touch events, sap.ui.table already supports native drag and drop on columns and supports touch

Comment: Unfortunately the eventdelegate function isn't called in my context. My view creates a countainer which i fill dynamically inside my controller. the content for the container comes from fragments. i already deleted the fragments and placed the controls directly into the container. still the eventdelegate function isnt called for the table.

Comment: Did you extend the control, relying view onafterrendering wont get trigger for a context change

Comment: I thought this delegate thing is working out of the box. You are right, i forgot to extend :(